# How do i add logo in wordpress studiopress (glam theme)?

Tags: menus, navigation, genesis-theme-framework, logo

i am beginner at wordpress. and i wanted to add navigation logo in my theme.
i am using glam theme develop by studiopress. 
i have used plugin (nav menu images) for navigation link.but it is adding logo with my existing primary menu. but i don't want to merge logo and primary menu (navigation links) together."i want to align logo on the left side, and navigation links to the right side of my navigation area. how do i do this.? please help me out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write custom code in PHP/HTML and style (CSS) the logo accordingly. As far as I can see, you can't add it through a plugin. Are you using [this theme](https://my.studiopress.com/themes/glam/)?